# Javascript/jQuery - Each skip all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, element

I'm getting all the elements on the document:

```
$("*").each(function(){
   var el = $(this);
});
```

What I need is to get all the elements but the children elements. I mean this:

```
<div> <!--GET IT-->
   <div></div> <!--DON'T GET IT-->
</div>

<div> <!--GET IT-->
   <div></div> <!--DON'T GET IT-->
   <label></label> <!--DON'T GET IT-->
</div>
```

How can I filter that?

Comment: So all direct descendants of the `body` then?

Comment: The problem is that all the elements are absolute positioned into a `div`. I'm trying to get all elements and make them relative to the parent. The selector would be that `div` and what I'm wanting to get are all direct descendants of that `div`.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`$(thatdiv).children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) then?  You may want to edit your question to make it more precise about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the parent element of outermost div elements and then use immediate child selector to get first level child element.

Let us assume you have above markup in body container. Then you can use

```
$('body >  *').each(function(){
  var el = $(this);
});
```

Comment: Or `$('body >  *')` to get every immediate child element if more than just  `div`s were desired

Comment: @Ash: indeed. i narrowed down it to div as only div elements were there

Comment: Thought so, was just adding my bit as supporting info. Looks like @Marcos beat me to it in his answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  this

```
 $('body > * ').each();
```

This targets all elements childrens of body, but don't target the childrens of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Look this: https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
$("parent > child").each(function(){

    $(this) /* children */

});
```